# Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: create_account, email, full_name

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Im Created 2 Models.

1. Account
2. UserProfil

First Of All, User Register email, fullname, password1, password2. The data Sending To Database in table **Account**.

Second, User Will Login, if success, he will go to dashboard. in dashboard have a profil Form.
In The Profil Form, He Will input data profil, likes number phone, birth date. etc. and will store in table **UserProfil**
All of data in UserProfil relationship with Account.

Im Try to create 'Profil Form'. Like This.

my Question is How To Put the data Full_Name in this form ?
i got Error Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: create_account, email, full_name ...

**authentication/models.py**

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
      email                   = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
      full_name               = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      create_account          = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
      is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_reviewer             = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)

      objects = CustomAccountManager()

      USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
      REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

      def __str__(self):
          return self.full_name
```

**dashboard/models.py**

```
class UserProfil(models.Model):
    jenis_kelamin_choice = (
       ('Pria', 'Pria'),
       ('Wanita', 'Wanita' ),
    )

    user                    = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    nik                     = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, unique=True)
    nidn                    = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

dashboard/views.py

```
class UserProfilFormView(CreateView):
    template_name       = 'dashboard/profil.html'
    form_class          = UserProfilForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    userPofil       = form.save(commit=False)
    userPofil.user  = Account.objects.get(user__full_name=self.request.user)
    userPofil.save()
    
    messages.success(self.request, 'Data Profil Berhasil Disimpan.')
    print(self.request.user)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

File Traceback :

```
Internal Server Error: /dashboard/profil
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 172, in post
return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
return self.form_valid(form)
File "D:\Project\hibahinternal\dashboard\views.py", line 26, in 
form_valid
userPofil.user  = Account.objects.get(user__full_name=self.request.user)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 424, in get
clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, 
**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 941, in filter
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 968, in 
_filter_or_exclude_inplace
self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1393, in add_q
clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1412, in _add_q
child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1286, in build_filter
lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1112, in solve_lookup_type
_, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, 
self.get_meta())
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1539, in names_to_path
raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into 
field. Choices are: create_account, email, full_name, groups, id, 
is_active, is_admin, is_reviewer, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, 
logentry, password, user_permissions, userprofil
[20/Dec/2021 19:31:48] "POST /dashboard/profil HTTP/1.1" 500 136397
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback, [edit] your question.

Comment: i'm just update the traceback. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Account` has no `user` field, this also would not make much sense, since that is the user account. You do not need to make a query to the `Account` model anyway: `request.user` works with the user model, here account, so you can use `request.user` directly:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class UserProfilFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/profil.html'
    form_class = UserProfilForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = request.user
        messages.success(self.request, 'Data Profil Berhasil Disimpan.')
        print(self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: Got a new Error , No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model. Where i found the documentation. i think i should learn more.

Comment: @You should add a `success_url`, or override `get_success_url` to specify to what URL to redirect in case the creation was successful.